# How to link a project owned by organisation to Google Play Developer API?

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console, google-console-developer

- `user_1@foobar.com` is the owner of a google play console account `project_1`.
- organization `foobar` owns google developer console project `project_2`
- `user_2@foobar.com` is the owner of `foobar` and invited `user_1@foobar.com` to `project_2`.

Can `user_1@foobar.com` link `project_2` to `project_1` to use Google Play Developer API?

#### google play console

There is no google developer origination console project `project_2`

[image: google play console]